# Magento Product Feed extension

Tags: product-list, export

I need a extension or script that exports product to csv file as following. I know there is no code or anything but could you please help me find a solution for this. thanks

Our Feed Requirement            Field we could use from your feed

```
Product ID                                 column A  -  sku

Product Name                          column B  -  product_name

Product Price                            column C  -  product_price

Product URL                              column F  -  product_url

Product Description                 column D  -  product_description

Product Image URL                  column G -  image_url         

Product Category                     column E  -  category_name
```

Comment: you have to create the CSV file via script

Comment: I would recommend this extension https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-product-feed-manager.html as this allows you to create feeds for any system like Facebook, Google, DooFinder, Amazon and many more

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple script in the root of your magento instance like this:
Let's name it `export.php`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app(); 
$storeId = 1; //the store id for the export
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId));
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//only active products
$lines = array();
//headers
$lines[] = array("Product ID","Product Name","Product Price","Product URL","Product Description","Product Image URL","Product Category");
//each product on one line:
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $line = array();
    $line[] = $product->getSku();//column A
    $line[] = $product->getName();//column b
    $line[] = $product->getFinalPrice();//column c
    $line[] = $product->getProductUrl(); //column F ?
    $line[] = $product->getDescription();//column D ?
    $line[] = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->__toString(); //column G
    $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection();  
    $categoryNames = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categoryNames[] = $category->getName();
    } 
    $line[] = implode(' | ', $categoryNames); //column E ?
    $lines[] = $line;
}
```

now you ca just print the contents of `$lines` or write it directly in a csv

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo '"'.implode('","', $line).'"'."\n";
}
```

Now you just have to call the url "ROOT/export.php"  in your browser.

Comment: use fputcsv to handle quoting.

Comment: @Richard. Yes you are right. I just posted here the "heavy lifting". Writing data to a file should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Magento’s Import/Export Profiles

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles

Thanks

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but it does not export with categories.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Advanced Product Feeds extension (http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/advanced-product-feeds-generator.html) or MakeFeed service for magento (http://makefeed.com)

Answer (score 1):

Check this extension:
http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html

The developer also offers customization services and I have used them couple of times with no complains.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/magento-product-feed-export-module.html is quite a good option. It allows you to create custom output formats by applying xsl transformations to the order data.